# Why sleep is running before print here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
import time

print('test')
time.sleep(1)
print('add')
```

However this's working, Python print `test` and sleep 1 second, then print `add`.

But if I change my code to this:

```
import time

print('test', end='')
time.sleep(1)
print(' add')
```

Python will sleep 1 second first, then print `testadd`. How to fix this?
I need print `test` without `\n`, and sleep 1 second, then print `add` after it.

Comment: @tobias_k So that is `print()` doesn't run`sys.stdout.flush()`?

Comment: @tobias_k Okay, I've tried run `sys.stdout.flush()` myself and it works. Thanks :)

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23142556/2617068).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Well, understand now :)